# How do I turn the white flashing between pages in chrome to black?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, themes

I am using [deluminate chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/deluminate/iebboopaeangfpceklajfohhbpkkfiaa) for the dark theme but switching between pages, there is always a white loading screen flash. And I want to paint it black.

I know there are some questions already asking this, but their solution doesn't really help. Maybe there is a solution now since this a few years later.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the white loading screen while switching pages? And have you tried the [Invert Page Colors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/invert-page-colors/hjhdnhiofjddcapmffbllcpaodjmdphn) extension?

Comment: It's basically a totally white page that appears in-between two darken webpages for a second or two to give that visible "flash" effect.

Comment: That extension is not as good as Disluminate, it doesn't even darken properly